# Make element float right, but overflow and scroll if there isn't enough width

Tags: css, scroll, flexbox, navbar

I'm working on a navigation bar that will work on any screen sizes. For large screens, it's easy with two containers `float: left;` and `float: right;`. However the problem is when the screen goes too small or when there's too much content, the containers go on two separate lines and it looks bad.

Here's what I want to achieve (the last figure). The green rectangle indicates screen area (display width) and my desired behavior of elements on different widths.

> [image: hmm]

This is the code I have for now, with the addition of `resize: horizontal;` on the root container for easier testing.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

nav {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: scroll hidden;
  background-color: #EEE;
  border: 2px solid black;
  resize: horizontal;
}

.nav-left {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-right {
  float: right;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #00C;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: #08F;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-left">
    <div class="nav-item">Left</div>
    <div class="nav-item">Left</div>
    <div class="nav-item">Left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-right">
    <div class="nav-item">Right</div>
    <div class="nav-item">Right</div>
    <div class="nav-item">Right</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of *floating* why not make the `nav` also a flexbox, given that you are already using a *flexbox* for the `nav-left` and `nav-right` elements.

See demo below:

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

nav {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: scroll hidden;
  background-color: #EEE;
  border: 2px solid black;
  resize: horizontal;
  display: flex; /* added */
  justify-content: space-between; /* spread them horizontally */
}

.nav-left {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-right {
  float: right;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #00C;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: #08F;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-left">
    <div class="nav-item">Left</div>
    <div class="nav-item">Left</div>
    <div class="nav-item">Left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-right">
    <div class="nav-item">Right</div>
    <div class="nav-item">Right</div>
    <div class="nav-item">Right</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```